# Python any plot serving solution for a simple histogram of datetime series? Bokeh or Other

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-visualization, bokeh

Spent days circling around snippets and trying recipes relating to bokeh. Asking this here not what I was expecting to be necessary.

I have a large CSV of the structure:

```
ACQ_DATE
28/01/2017 0:00
28/01/2017 1:00
28/01/2017 2:00
29/01/2017 7:00
29/01/2017 7:00
30/01/2017 3:00
30/01/2017 3:00
30/01/2017 4:00
30/01/2017 4:00
31/01/2017 0:00
31/01/2017 9:00
...
```

I would like to serve an interactive histogram eventually, but even a simple plot with readable labels will do for now !!

With that dataframe loaded as df I have ended up with code scrambled from a bunch of other snippets all trying to do this but in different ways:

```
df['ACQ_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(gdf['ACQ_DATE'])
df['DTI'] = df['ACQ_DATE']
df.set_index('DTI', inplace=True)

data = df.groupby(df["ACQ_DATE"].dt.month).count()

hist, edges = np.histogram(data)

p = figure()
p.quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:], line_color="white")

main_row = row(p)
layout = column(main_row)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "Fire Points"
```

So it's trying to group the data into months for this example.

It gives me a plot, but with numbers as x-axis labels not date/months.

I'm very disappointed with the Bokeh documentation I find it disjointed and the whole Bokeh experience has been unexpectedly poor. Found this morning trying holoviews to be exactly the same experience which confused me I was expecting that was what it was built for... I was expecting for such a simple series to be able to throw it at a histogram object which would just do some counts and simple labels for goodness sakes, but no. Unbelievable really and every post touching on this seems to have a wildly different solution...

So, my question is about a simple solution for bokeh server, but I'm happy to look at anything that is clear and simple (sob sob, it's just a ts histogram!) using another library.

I am stunned that I just cant do (somelibplease).histogram(df, 'ACQ_DATE) or similar - I do not need squillions of plot options. 'holoview' didn't come through there unfortunately.

Obviously I'm new to plotting in python, and I won't be doing much in the future and do not need outrageous features/options, so spending days and days (months actually required methinks) to learn a lib to achieve this does not seem very pythonic at all.

Off to the pub, not used to being frustrated by Python!! All help greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Cheers

Comment: To clarify I don't mean to bag bokeh and holoview, I think they are awesome; concept, code and community. I just find it bewildering that timestamps aren't handled at a higher level, especially for hv. I hope the hv team can address this as I think it's a basic fundamental feature they've missed, as I'm exactly the type of user their lib is targeting and every single  dataset I'm handed these days seems to be a time series of sorts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said 'any' library in python, here's a solution using pandas' matplotlib wrapper.

```
import pandas as pd

#Copying your data 
a = pd.read_clipboard(header = None, sep="s+")
a.columns = ['ACQ_DATE']
a['ACQ_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(a['ACQ_DATE'])
```

Some augmentation of the frame, so that I could get the data to plot a histogram

```
date_groups = a.groupby(a['ACQ_DATE'].dt.date).size() 

date_groups
Out[44]: 
ACQ_DATE
2017-01-28    3
2017-01-29    2
2017-01-30    4
2017-01-31    2
dtype: int64
```

Finally, using pandas `plot.bar()` function,

```
date_groups.plot.bar(width=1.0) # width = 1, to make this more like histogram
```

[image]

---

**NB:** I agree that the `bokeh` documentation has a lot to improve.

---